# Benchmarking Ruby Code

Tags: ruby

I'm doing the following Ruby Tutorial https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/50-debugging/lessons/124-benchmarking_ruby_code. One of the exercises asks me to:

> use Ruby's super-awesome blocks to create a method which takes in a
>   block, executes it, and returns the time it took.

The exercise looks like this:

```
 def benchmark
   # your code here!
 end

 time_taken = benchmark do
   sleep 0.1
 end
 puts "Time taken #{time_taken}"
```

there is a hint (Need a hint?) below the exercise:

> 1. Ruby Blocks - [Introduction to Blocks in Ruby (Ruby Primer)](http://Introduction%20to%20Blocks%20in%20Ruby%20(Ruby%20Primer))

and i did so:

```
 def benchmark(time)
   begin_time = Time.now
   end_time = Time.now
   time.benchmark {|time| yield time}
 end

 time_taken = benchmark do
   sleep 0.1
 end
 puts "Time taken #{time_taken}
```

but received an error.

i am interested in: why is local variable - 'time_taken', suggested without representing an element after 'do'? or is it not necessary? Can anyone tell me how to write code to get the positive result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it much easier:

```
def benchmark
   begin_time = Time.now
   yield
   end_time = Time.now
   end_time - begin_time
 end

 time_taken = benchmark do
   sleep 0.1
 end

 puts "Time taken #{time_taken}"
```

First you collect the time and store in in variable `begin_time`, then `yield` - so run the block, then collect the end time. Return the difference. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty far off, and not really at all salvagible.

Your benchmark method should look like this pseudo code:

```
def benchmark
  let begin_time -> current time
  execute the block
  let end_time -> current_time
  return endtime - begintime
end
```

As far as executing the block being passed in, there is no `time.benchmark` method, I'm not sure where that came from, and you do not need to pass anything into the block. You want a single, simple `yield`.